# Use redirectTo if you using also children parameter, is this possible?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular2-routing

As you probably already now in the latest `@angular/router 3.0.0-rc.1` you are not allowed to user `redirectTo` parameter if you also use the `children` parameter.

But for sure in some cases this is something that you need like in my case.
For example what I want is to redirect to first child all requests to the parent router.

Here's my router:

```
{
    path: 'project/:id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ProjectPropertiesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'stats',
        component: ProjectStatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

I want everyone that goes to the `project/:id` route to get redirected to the first child (`properties`) in my case.

Is this possible somehow?

If I try like this:

```
{
    path: 'project/:id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    redirectTo: 'properties',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ProjectPropertiesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'stats',
        component: ProjectStatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm getting this error of course:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Invalid configuration of route 'project/:id': redirectTo and children cannot be used together

Answer (score 102, accepted):

An empty child route should do the job:

```
  {
    path: 'project/:id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'properties',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ProjectPropertiesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'stats',
        component: ProjectStatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Thx! The same time I was answering exactly the same thing :) but thx anyway this is the correct answer. ;)

Comment: Glad I could almost help! ;)

Comment: I wish I saw this question/answer instead of wasting a lot of time trying to get default redirect working. Thanks @j2L4e

Comment: I had to add pathMatch: 'full' after the redirectTo line.

Comment: doesn't work with pathMatch: "full", you have to use prefix as @user2735883 specified below

Comment: With `pathMatch: 'prefix'` I don't think you'd be able to navigate to 'stats' in the above example. Also `prefix` is the default so you could just remove `pathMatch`.

Answer (score 4):

j2L4e answer is correct, but I was also forced to set the 'pathMatch' type as 'prefix' ..

**pathMatch: 'prefix'**

```
  {
    path: 'project/:id',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'properties',
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
      },
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ProjectPropertiesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'stats',
        component: ProjectStatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me in angular 15+.
just remove `/:id` for root route with children

```
  {
    path: 'project',
    component: ProjectComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'properties',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'properties',
        component: ProjectPropertiesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'stats',
        component: ProjectStatsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```